# Stenciljs @Method not working

Tags: javascript, web-component, stenciljs, stencil-component

I'm struggling to get **@Method** in stenciljs working - any help would be appreciated.

Here's my component code with a function called **setName** that I want to expose on my component:

```
import { Component, Prop, Method, State } from "@stencil/core";

@Component({
  tag: "my-name",
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {

  @Prop() first: string;
  @Prop() last: string;
  @State() dummy: string;

  @Method() setName(first: string, last: string): void {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.dummy = first + last;
  }
  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello, World! I'm {this.first} {this.last}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the html and script that references the component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0">
  <title>Stencil Component Starter</title>
  <script src="/build/mycomponent.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <my-name  />

  <script>
    var myName = document.querySelector("my-name");
    myName.setName('Bob', 'Smith');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a screen shot of the error I'm getting which is ***Uncaught TypeError: myName.setName is not a function***:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Methods are not immediately available on a component; they have to be loaded/hydrated by Stencil before you can use them.

Components have a `componentOnReady` function that resolve when the component is ready to be used. So something like:

```
var myName = document.querySelector("my-name");
myName.componentOnReady().then(() => {
  myName.setName('Bob', 'Smith');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I get "Uncaught TypeError: myName.componentOnReady is not a function"

Comment: Correction - after updating to stencil 0.8.2 this worked!

Comment: @CarlRippon here is the reason why it worked after upgrading to stencil https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md

Comment: This is the current way to way to call a methond in StencilJs
.
.
.
(async () => {
  await customElements.whenDefined('todo-list');
  const todoListElement = document.querySelector('todo-list');
  await todoListElement.showPrompt();
})();

Comment: I have Stencil 2.7.0 and still not working, it's PAINFUL.

Answer (score 11):

Just posting another answer because this has since changed, with Stencil One.

All `@Method` decorated methods are now immediately available on the component, but they are required to be `async`, so that you can immediately call them (and they resolve once the component is ready). The use of `componentOnReady` for this is now obsolete.

However, you should make sure that the component is already defined in the custom element registry, using the [`whenDefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined) method of the custom element registry.

```
<script>
(async () => {
  await customElements.whenDefined('my-name');

  // the component is registered now, so its methods are immediately available
  const myComp = document.querySelector('my-name');

  if (myComp) {
    await myComp.setName('Bob', 'Smith');
  }
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you should not use @Method , it is not a best practice. We should always minimize the usage of @Method. This helps us to  scale the app easily.

Instead pass data through @Prop and @Watch for it.

Ok , in your case , Please add async before the method name